# Can tags be renamed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is a tag [amazonapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazonapi) and I believe <s>the forum</s> Stack Exchange uses hyphenation so the tag should be [amazon-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-api).

Is editing tags a privilege or is it moderators only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree - have remapped [amazonapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazonapi) to [amazon-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-api) - keeps it consistent and readable.

Answer (score 2):

Only a moderator can rename a tag. However, since this tag has only 20 questions and no usage guidance, you can simply retag these questions to [amazon-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-api), since you have the [Create Tags privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (earned at 1500 reputation). If there are no questions with some tag, it will be automatically deleted after some time.

Comment: So, I tried that: `You are attempting to create the tag [amazon-api]; however the tag [amazonapi] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta`

Comment: @User Well, I didn't know that. I guess you have to wait for a moderator then.